# C#: Get complete desktop size?

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, screen, screen-resolution

How do I find out the size of the entire desktop? **Not** the "working area" and **not** the "screen resolution", both of which refer to only one screen. I want to find out the total width and height of the virtual desktop of which each monitor is showing only a part.

Comment: Maybe the "complete desktop size" will depend on how the screens are positioned. Not sure how to calculate that, but you still can catch the number of screens and resolution of each screen with System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You have two options:

1. **PresentationFramework.dll**

   ```
   SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth   
   SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight
   ```
2. **System.Windows.Forms.dll**

   ```
   SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width   
   SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
   ```

Use the *first option* if you developing a WPF application.

Comment: More of answers like this! Short, correct and esthetically pleasing!

Comment: I've found scenarios where these values will only register one screen if scaling is enabled. May be hardware dependent, not sure yet.

Comment: That's likely given back in 2011 multi-desktop scaling wasn't a thing. @KellyElton update the answer if you find a fix.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution to this, I think it's a bug. I'm using a Blackweb BWA17HO002 usb3 to hdmi adapter, with an intel HD 520 (laptop). When I have the display scaling > 150% on the laptop, these values will only return the laptop screen dimensions. Once I remove the scaling, then it registers the second monitor.

Answer (score 35):

I think it's time to bring this answer up to date with a little LINQ, which makes it easy to get the entire desktop size with a single expression.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    Screen.AllScreens.Select(screen=>screen.Bounds)
    .Aggregate(Rectangle.Union)
    .Size
);
```

My original answer follows:

---

I guess what you want is something like this:

```
int minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
minx = miny = int.MaxValue;
maxx = maxy = int.MinValue;

foreach(Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens){
    var bounds = screen.Bounds;
    minx = Math.Min(minx, bounds.X);
    miny = Math.Min(miny, bounds.Y);
    maxx = Math.Max(maxx, bounds.Right);
    maxy = Math.Max(maxy, bounds.Bottom);
}

Console.WriteLine("(width, height) = ({0}, {1})", maxx - minx, maxy - miny);
```

Keep in mind that this doesn't tell the whole story.  It is possible for multiple monitors to be staggered, or arranged in a nonrectangular shape.  Therefore, it may be that not all of the space between (minx, miny) and (maxx, maxy) is visible.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the code could be a bit simpler using `Rectangle.Union`:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue, int.MinValue, int.MinValue);

foreach(Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    rect = Rectangle.Union(rect, screen.Bounds);

Console.WriteLine("(width, height) = ({0}, {1})", rect.Width, rect.Height);
```

Comment: I'm Ukrainian programmer. I'm verifying that this code is working from the box. Just copy and paste.

Answer (score 16):

Check:

```
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the physical pixel size of the monitor you can use this.

```
static class DisplayTools
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    private enum DeviceCap
    {
        Desktopvertres = 117,
        Desktophorzres = 118
    }

    public static Size GetPhysicalDisplaySize()
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();

        int physicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.Desktopvertres);
        int physicalScreenWidth = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.Desktophorzres);

        return new Size(physicalScreenWidth, physicalScreenHeight);
    }


}
```

Comment: This one is the first one that reports the correct size, but only for a single monitor. 

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer the question, but merely adds additional insight on a window's Point (location) within all the screens).

Use the code below to find out if a Point (e.g. last known Location of window) is within the bounds of the overall Desktop.  If not, reset the window's Location to the default **pBaseLoc**;

Code does not account for the TaskBar or other Toolbars, yer on yer own there.

Example Use:  Save the Window location to a database from **station A**.  User logs into **station B** with 2 monitors and moves the window to the 2nd monitor, logs out saving new location.  Back to **station A** and the window wouldn't be shown unless the above code is used.

My further resolve implemented saving the userID and station's IP (& winLoc) to database or local user prefs file for a given app, then load in user pref for that station & app.

```
Point pBaseLoc = new Point(40, 40)
int x = -500, y = 140;
Point pLoc = new Point(x, y);
bool bIsInsideBounds = false;

foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    bIsInsideBounds = s.Bounds.Contains(pLoc);
    if (bIsInsideBounds) { break; }
}//foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)

if (!bIsInsideBounds) { pLoc = pBaseLoc;  }

this.Location = pLoc;
```

Comment: If you *know* that this doesn’t answer the question, why are you posting it as an answer to the question? Shouldn’t the first sentence have rung an alarm bell?

Comment: On this other hand, this is exactly what I was looking for when I came searching on this topic

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to get the "real" screen-size, is to get the values directly from the video-controller.

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace MOS
    {
        public class ClassMOS
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController"); 

                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CurrentHorizontalResolution: {0}", queryObj["CurrentHorizontalResolution"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("CurrentVerticalResolution: {0}", queryObj["CurrentVerticalResolution"]);
                    }
                }
                catch (ManagementException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

This should do the job ;)
Greetings ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bounds of `System.Drawing`.

You can create a function like this

```
public System.Windows.Form.Screen[] GetScreens(){
    Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
    return screens;
}
```

and than you can get the screen one, two, etc. in a variable like this:

```
System.Windows.Form.Screen[] screens = func.GetScreens();
System.Windows.Form.Screen screen1 = screens[0];
```

then you can get the bounds of the screen:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle screen1Bounds = screen1.Bounds;
```

With this code you will get all the properties like `Width`, `Height`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This method returns the rectangle that contains all of the screens' bounds by using the lowest values for Left and Top, and the highest values for Right and Bottom...

```
static Rectangle GetDesktopBounds() {
   var l = int.MaxValue;
   var t = int.MaxValue;
   var r = int.MinValue;
   var b = int.MinValue;
   foreach(var screen in Screen.AllScreens) {
      if(screen.Bounds.Left   < l) l = screen.Bounds.Left  ;
      if(screen.Bounds.Top    < t) t = screen.Bounds.Top   ;
      if(screen.Bounds.Right  > r) r = screen.Bounds.Right ;
      if(screen.Bounds.Bottom > b) b = screen.Bounds.Bottom;
   }
   return Rectangle.FromLTRB(l, t, r, b);
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little.

Comment: It loops through all the screens. If the left edge is lesser than the variable 'l' it sets 'l' to this new value, if the bottom edge is greater than 'b' then it sets that. The end result is l, t, r, b are set to the left, top, right, and bottom edges of your entire visible desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Get the **Size** of a virtual display without any dependencies

```
public enum SystemMetric
{
    VirtualScreenWidth = 78, // CXVIRTUALSCREEN 0x0000004E 
    VirtualScreenHeight = 79, // CYVIRTUALSCREEN 0x0000004F 
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric metric);

public static Size GetVirtualDisplaySize()
{
    var width = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.VirtualScreenWidth);
    var height = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.VirtualScreenHeight);

    return new Size(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Best answer IMO, no explicit dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Values, derived from SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN and so on are physical coordinates and not equals to logical coordinates at screen scaling 125%, 150%, 175% in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that many window manipulations are not yet available or may not ever be made available. I've had the greatest success with PInvoke.User32 nuget package.

```
var screenX = PInvoke.User32.GetSystemMetrics(PInvoke.User32.SystemMetric.SM_CXSCREEN);
var screenY = PInvoke.User32.GetSystemMetrics(PInvoke.User32.SystemMetric.SM_CYSCREEN);
```