# Is there a way to determine the physical size of the monitor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In inches, e.g. 21' monitor.  The app is a standard WinForms app.

EDIT: It appears there really isn't a reliable way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: The title forgot to mention that the OP wants the physical size of the monitor image (in inches), not the desktop resolution in sq. pixels.

Comment: @Andreas Your suggestion added

Comment: I could easily give you pixel size but, that's all...

Comment: What if you are using a projector? Then the size of the screen depends on the distance between the projector and the viewing screen. How could you possibly figure that out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Get complete desktop size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317235/c-get-complete-desktop-size)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: No, this is an entirely different question. This is about the monitor's physical size...

Comment: You have to be careful, some older monitors report their size including the bezel too! :-(

I think this will be difficult, if not impossible without asking the user, or performing some sort of calibration.

Comment: This question is a bit incorrectly tagged. It is really a languange-agnostic problem.

Comment: @Andreas: Some monitors just lie about their size, and Windows (well, at least for a long time) tends to just assume a fixed pixel density. Maybe things are better now, but I could believe things still being in this sorry state…

Comment: Is there a call to get the screen resolution in DPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking about two ways that might work under special conditions:

- Try to get the name of the monitor hardware. On my dual-monitor system, I use one SyncMaster 205BW and one SyncMaster 173T. These are 20″ and 17″ monitors. You see what I mean? One problem, however, is that I am not sure if you programmatically can obtain these strings. Windows appears to only obtain SyncMaster: [screenres.png](http://privat.rejbrand.se/screenres.png).
- You can use [`GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(GetDesktopWindow), VERTSIZE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(VS.85).aspx) to obtain "Height, in millimeters, of the physical screen." and similarly with `HORZSIZE` and the "width". But this will only work if you have calibrated your display, I believe. At least on my system, the values are much larger than the actual height and width...
- I have no idea about your context, but if your app really does need the physical size of the end-user's output device, why not *ask* him? You could easily ask for the monitor's size during setup (e.g. using the excellent Inno Setup), and store the value in the registry. Then it is trivial to write a procedure `GetPhysicalMonitorSize` that simply reads the value from the registry.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be guaranteed. Windows cannot know the size of the monitor unless its driver interrogates it and reports the reply to windows.

However, you might want to try

```
SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
```

or  `GetDeviceCaps(dc, HORZSIZE)`  and `GetDeviceCaps(dc, VERTSIZE)` and then calulate the square on the hypotenuse.

Note that there is also an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317235/c-get-complete-desktop-size) to identical question right here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Web app or desktop app?  All you can find out about the web app is the browser's screen resolution, using javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">

var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

if( width < 1280 || height < 1024)
{
    alert("This web page is best viewed with a screen resolution of 1280 by 1024 or higher.  Your current resolution is " + width + " by " + height + ".  If possible please change your resolution.");
}
else
{
    alert("Your screen resolution is pretty big!")
}
</script>
```

For a desktop app, you do this:

```
MessageBox.Show( "Monitor Size:" +
   SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize );
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the EDID in the registry to obtain the physical screen size. The monitor's driver reports the physical screen size to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no .NET-specific way, you can always use the native Windows API: [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(VS.85).aspx) with `SM_CYSCREEN` or `SM_CXSCREEN`.

Comment: GetSystemMetrics only brings back things like resolution.  I want the size of the monitor (e.g. 21' monitor).

Comment: That *is* a lot more difficult, for values of `difficult == impossible`