# How can I programmatically determine the size of my desktop?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, window-position

I'm trying to save / restore the window size, state and position of a `System::Windows::Forms::Form` and want to make sure that if the window was previously on another monitor and the app is started up when only a snogle monitor is available, that it puts itself somewhere on-screen.

So how can I determine the current desktop size and whether my application is out of bounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Get complete desktop size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317235/c-get-complete-desktop-size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the best solution would be to use the native methods [GetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518.aspx) and [SetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544.aspx) in user32.dll. These automatically handle all the edge cases.

A sample WPF implementation using them can be found at http://jake.ginnivan.net/2010/04/remembering-wpf-windows-position-2/ From that you could do the same for WinForms.

Comment: +1/Accepted ..although by the time I read this, I'd already rolled my own :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen_properties.aspx) class?

The `Screen.WorkingArea` property will give you the desktop size of your display.