# Misbehaving Screen.AllScreens.Length

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

i am having windows7 32 bit in laptop with extended monitor. **Screen.AllScreens.Length** is returning **1** while calling from **Windows service** , but from **windows application** or **console application** is giving me as **2**.

Comment: Is your service set to allow interaction with the desktop? If not, I can imagine Windows faking a single screen. Out of curiosity, why are you trying to get the number of screens anyway?

Comment: Sounds like your service is only detecting your main laptop screen, doesnt it. Is your service configured to run without a login? If so, it may be that the extended screen is only visible once a driver is loaded at user login time. Try setting your service to login.

Comment: service is running in **Local system account** and allow service to interact with desktop is **also checked**.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you do not have a screen as a "normal" windows service; nor do you have GDI/GDI+ functions that behave correctly.

See [Get Desktop Size from Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507612/get-desktop-size-from-windows-service) for some more information.

See [Allow service to interact with desktop in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237225/windows-service-allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop) to interact with the desktop.  Note that this is NOT allowed in Vista.