# Gather [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens via Powershell remotely

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am creating a powershell script to gather information about a desktops video resolution, below is part of the code. The problem I am having is using my script remotely. Using an input file and connecting to a remote host works fine, but gathering data from remote computer instead of local using the "$ColsResolutions = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens" is being troublesome.

As you can see "Get-WmiObject -computername $Target" and simliar work fine remotely, but how do I use it with the AllScreens cmd? As it stands, the script works perfectly except it gathers local AllSCreens instead of remote host. Is it possible?

```
Write-Output "..Monitor Information"
$ColsMonitors = Get-WmiObject -computername $Target Win32_PnPEntity

Write-Output "..Video Information"
$ColsVideos = Get-WmiObject -computername $Target win32_videocontroller

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$ColsResolutions = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
```

**EDIT:**
Note, I am using AllSCreens insteasd of Win32_DesktopMonitor because I have workstations that contain multiple video cards & monitors with different resolutions. And I need to audit and retrieve the information for all displays.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Screen.AllScreens does not have a remote version so you need to use PowerShell remoting to call that method on a remote machine. If you use PowerShell remoting you end up in a PowerShell Windows Service which has a default desktop. This desktop is not visible, belongs to the system account and has no real screens. Therefore it will simply not give you the result you want. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243738/misbehaving-screen-allscreens-length).