# SystemInformation.VirtualScreen changes when outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

How can I get the results of `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen` AND `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` to work the same both inside and outside of Visual Studio for a WinForms application?

```
private void ShowScreenSize()
{
    MessageBox.Show( SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.ToString() );
}
```

When I run the code above INSIDE Visual Studio it shows:**{X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}**

When I run the code above OUTSIDE Visual Studio it shows:
**{X=0,Y=0,Width=3072,Height=1728}**

I also get the same value difference when using `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`
My OS is Windows 8.1 and my native monitor resolution is 3840x2160

Also, I notice UI scaling of the application is normal when run inside of Visual Studio, but is stretched slightly when outside.  I'm guessing that Visual Studio  prevents the built in Windows UI scaling as my system is configured for UI scaling one step larger than minimum.  Might that be affecting the value of `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen`?

My final goal is to capture the full desktop using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`. I want to get the full rectangle that includes all monitors in the whole virtual desktop.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1317235/21567).

Comment: No, While I am using the value identified in that question, but the result is changing depending on whether I am inside or outside of VisualStudio.  My question is how can I make it work the same outside as it does inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe you should try using the `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth` property instead - as it seems to be apt for WPF applications (if you have a WPF application). Otherwise just ignore this. ;-)

Comment: I am running a WinForms App, not a WPF app.  I cannot see the SystemParameters object.

Comment: Yes, it would be defined in `PresentationCore.dll`. But never mind, I just check the implementations of both on `sourceof.net` and both are basically identical. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: 3840 / 3072 = 1.25.  You must declare your app [dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) if you don't want to be lied to.

Comment: That fixed it - if you post that as answer I will mark it:  Here is the code:   `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        SetProcessDPIAware();`