# How to get screen size with .net6 and avalonia in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, avaloniaui

How would I get primary screen size in C# (primarily width) with avalonia (for MS Windows)? Getting screen size through SystemParameters, i.e. `System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth`, does not work here.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not work here" - what does `PrimaryScreenWidth` return, exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure If it's a tied to .net6 or specific to AvaloniaUI, but namespace "System.Windows.SystemParameters" is not available in project.

Comment: Maybe Avalonia is using WinForms. You want to use a WPF extension. Does this work?
int Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. But if I understand correctly, Avalonia is built on WPF, although it is not exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I checked it works. Unless only for Windows, but based on the question, this is not a problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656496

```
static class DisplayTools
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    private enum DeviceCap
    {
        Desktopvertres = 117,
        Desktophorzres = 118
    }

    public static Size GetPhysicalDisplaySize()
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();

        int physicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.Desktopvertres);
        int physicalScreenWidth = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.Desktophorzres);

        return new Size(physicalScreenWidth, physicalScreenHeight);
    }
}
```

UPD:
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth uses GetSystemMetrics.
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/SystemParameters.cs#L3080C5-L3080C5

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

public const int CM_CXSCREEN = 0; // Width
public const int CM_CYSCREEN = 1; // Height
```

But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics#:%7E:text=is%20not%20supported.-,SM_CXSCREEN,-0) says it's the same.

> The width of the screen of the primary display monitor, in pixels.
> This is the same value obtained by calling GetDeviceCaps as follows:
> GetDeviceCaps( hdcPrimaryMonitor, HORZRES).

Comment: I suspect this approach will return incorrect (or rather: stub or pretend values) given how frequently GDI is sandboxed in WIndows lately... (e.g. when you run a program with high-DPI mode disabled, for example)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).